# Mosquitto giving error on launch

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I installed Mosquitto 1.4.9 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine from source files

I ran a test and things worked fine with localhost but when I tried to connect using my domain I got a connection refused error message.

When I went back to my mosquitto.conf file I found I had made a typo in my url so I corrected the typo (I even tried with the IP Addy in place of the domain).

I then killed the running Mosquitto process and when I ran `sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

I got the following output:

```
1513023494: mosquitto version 1.4.9 (build date 2017-12-11 13:46:59-0500) starting
1513023494: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1513023494: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1513023494: Error: Cannot assign requested address
```

When I remove the domain and put in localhost I get:

```
1513024906: mosquitto version 1.4.9 (build date 2017-12-11 13:46:59-0500) starting
1513024906: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1513024906: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
```

My mosquitto.conf file looks like this:

```
listener 8883 <domain>.com
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
persistence_file mosquitto.db
log_dest syslog
log_dest stdout
log_dest topic
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile
```

Comment: What happens if you leave the domain out (it should bind to all available addresses)

Comment: Perfect that resolved the issue and it now works!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by hardillb,

Removing the FQDN, Localhost, or IP address from the Listener line allowed mosquitto to launch properly and accept connections on the FQDN.

Comment: I'm going to guess this is because mosquitto can't resolve the name to a IP address that matches an available interface

Comment: I was thinking something like that today. I realized this morning that my server isn't using the FQDN I specified in the listener entry. Odd that the IP didn't work though... Anyways removing it resolved that issue, Thanks!

Comment: Most probably because you were using the public IP of your router not your pi